# Client-side certificates

Tags: security, apache-2.2, ssl, openssl, x509

My company purchased a wildcard certificate from a vendor. This certificate was successfully configured with Apache 2.2 to secure a subdomain. Everything on the SSL side works.

Now I'm required to generate x509 client-side certificates to issue for this subdomain. I'm following along this page: (http://www.vanemery.com/Linux/Apache/apache-SSL.html), starting with "Creating Client Certificates for Authentication".

I've generated the p12 files and successfully imported them into Firefox. When I browse to the site now, I get an error in FireFox that says "The connection to the server was reset while the page was loading."

I think my problem is coming from not signing the client-side correctly. When I sign the client-side certificate, I'm using the PEM file (RapidSSL_CA_bundle.pem) from RapidSSL (who we bought the certificate from) for the -CA argument. For the -CAkey argument, I'm using the private key of the server. Is this correct?

Comment: I think ServerFault would be a more appropriate place for a question since it's clearly a configuration issue and not a programming one.

Comment: My bad. Didn't realize this was misplaced.

Comment: No, that is not correct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I do not think that the license for a wildcard certificate allows you to use it for signing other certificates. You need to be a certificate authority to be able to do that.

Comment: Thanks. I think after trying to talk with my CA's technical support I got to this conclusion.

Answer (score 0):

Apache is probably resetting the connection.  Try looking at your log files.  If you are on *nix system this should be in `/var/log/apache/error.log`.

Answer (score 0):

Use openssl to view the contents of your generated certificate.  It will then be obvious if your signing is working correctly.

```
openssl x509 -text -noout -in <yoursignedcert>
```

If that looks OK and appears to have an Issuer field that reflects where it is signed try using openssl to attach to your server and see what it is expecting.

```
openssl s_client -connect <host>:port -CAfile <yourtrustcert> -cert <yoursignedcert>
```

That should give some clues as to whether the server is requesting your certificate or not.